# How do I add timezone to date/time formatted by strftime?

Tags: datetime, nxlog

I need to format date/time with a correct time zone and using this format string: `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S`. However, it's using local time. How can I make it format time including time zone, or using UTC time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the timezone with *%Z* or *%z*.

strftime can only generate local time.

Comment: This option doesn't work correctly, at least on Windows. It always outputs textual time zone name only.